# How to split an existing SurfaceView to many?

Tags: android, surfaceview, rtmp, surface

I have a SurfaceView which includes many peoples' face streamings

[image: pull a stream from rtmp server]

Now i want to split the SurfaceView to six different SurfaceViews.
EveryOne should inclues only one people face streaming.

So,the question is how to split or clone a SurfaceView ? thank u

Comment: can you use different surface view for different people ?

Comment: it's ok,and I want to know how to split the exiting SurfaceView to many?

Comment: just place 6 `SurfaceView` on the layout

Comment: @VladyslavMatviienko but , how to split the existing SurfaceView to 6 ? I only have one existing SurfaceView .

Comment: do you want to split the video from that SurfaceVIew? You cant. (you can but it will be too slow to show in real time). WHy you want to split it?

Comment: @VladyslavMatviienko I have a rtmp streaming which includes many faces, i want to split the video to 6 for  freedomly layout

Comment: you should then ask a question about how to split the video stream probably